# Apache crashing

Tags: apache, vps

yesterday I moved one of websites I manage to my VPS and today strange thing happened. None of my websites were working while FTP, SSH and VPS administration were working. First thing that came to my mind was to restart Apache and it helped. Then it happened again few hours later and restart again helped. So I looked into Apache error log file(it has 10MB) and there are about 110 000 lines of only these two errors:

```
[Mon Jul 27 09:06:00.889287 2015] [core:warn] [pid 15544] AH00045: child process 26930 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
```

and

```
postdrop: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/756694.28641: Disk quota exceeded
```

My VPS has 512MB of RAM and I do not think there are more than 100 people a day visiting my websites so I was surprised when I found out RAM usage like this http://postimg.org/image/7il6j3rcd/

May the usage of RAM be the cause? This matrimoni user seems like one of websites(http://matrimoniodenataliaylukas.sk/) I have on VPS, but I have no idea why it has so many processes and uses so much memory.

Do you have any ideas what might cause my Apache to stop working randomly?

Answer (score 0):

```
[Mon Jul 27 09:06:00.889287 2015] [core:warn] [pid 15544] AH00045: child process 26930 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
```

This error occurs when child processes were not terminated, and a SIGTERM(Signal: Terminate - default signal to kill a process) is sent. The main reason behind this error is heavy or buggy scripts, memory exhaustion, infinite loops etc.You should try Lowering down your MaxClients settings. Most probably you are running more Apache processes than you have physical memory for.

```
postdrop: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/756694.28641: Disk quota exceeded
```

This error indicates that the mailbox of user is full. Try removing unwanted emails and reboot the host.